# JOLT transform - Remove empty node in the JSON Array

Tags: json, jolt

Can someone help with Jolt spec for the below requirement?
Input:

```json
{
  "individuals": [
    {
      "individual": {
        "LastName": "Ind1-LastName",
        "firstName": "Ind1-FirstName"
      }
    },
    {
      "individual": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "linkedIndividuals": [
    {
      "individual": {
        "LastName": "Ind1-LastName",
        "firstName": "Ind1-FirstName"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dive deep upto the innermost node in order to encounter the key name without a value, then add the respective replacement symbols(`&3.[&2].&1.&`) consecutively to construct the JSON body again by using such a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "linked&3.[&2].&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]